# How flink reduce data to one sink

Tags: apache-flink

I am learning flink,I try keyBy the data and reduce it then sink to print,but why my sink invoke method is not call?

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(configuration);

        env.setBufferTimeout(0);
        List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            counts.add(i);
        }
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> value = env.fromCollection(counts)
                .keyBy(c -> c)
                .windowAll(GlobalWindows.create())
                .reduce(new ReduceFunction<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer reduce(Integer count, Integer t1) throws Exception {
                        return count + t1;
                    }
                });

        value.addSink(new SinkFunction<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(Integer value, Context context) throws Exception {
                log.info("sink count:" + value);//this method is not call
            }
        });

        value.print();
        env.execute("count");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using ***GlobalWindow*** which probably needs a trigger.

> This windowing scheme is only useful if you also specify a custom trigger. Otherwise, no computation will be performed, as the global window does not have a natural end at which we could process the aggregated elements.

you can know more by reading documentation [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#global-windows)

And you don't need a special sink for printing out your results. `value.print();` will do the job.